# Finding Path to a Node - Tree with multiple children

Tags: java, kotlin, data-structures, tree

I have been scratching my head to find a solution to this problem. I am not very good with data structures and it seems that my brain melts a little whenever I have to do anything to do with trees.

Suppose we have a Node():

```
Node(name: String, children: List<Node>?)
```

And we have a tree made up of these nodes:

```
var node6 = Node("6", null)
var node5 = Node("5", null)
var node4 = Node("4", null)
var node3 = Node("3", listOf(node5, node6))
var node2 = Node("2", null)
var node1 = Node("1", listOf(node2, node3, node4))
```

What approach could I take to find the path (stored) to node6 while only having the root available?

Thank you kindly for any advice you could offer!

---

Solution as per [JayC667](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1932011/jayc667)'s guidance:

```
fun recursiveCheck(
    nodeA: Node,
    nodePath: Stack<Node>,
    nodeToFind: String
) : Boolean {
    // Push param node to stack
    nodePath.push(nodeA)

    // Check param node
    if(nodeA.name == nodeToFind) {
        return true
    }

    if(nodeA.children != null) {
        // Iterate over all children using recursive check
        for(child in nodeA.children!!) {
            // child found as param node
            if(recursiveCheck(child, nodePath, nodeToFind)) return true
        }
    }

    // Did not find node, popping off stack
    nodePath.pop()
    return false
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far and also the code describing the structure of the tree?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko I have updated the question with a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. If the node only exists once in the tree and is reachable from the root, of course.

Use a Stack as node path stack:

1. **Starting method**: create stack, call *recursive check method*, params: (root node, node path stack, node to find)
2. **Recursive Check method**: push param node to stack, check param node, iterate over all children + for each child call *recursive check method*. If child was found as param node or in the subcalls, immediately return true (and return)
3. each time you leave the *recursive check method* (at the end, if you have NOT found the node), pop the current element off the stack.
4. if in the *starting method* the *Recursive Check method* has returned true, your node path will lie on the stack

Comment: Thank you for this, I will write up some code and update my post accordingly!